# How to check if the file is downloaded with curl

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

I am writing a shell script, I need to download 6 files from internet, In the script I have done it as

```
curl a
curl b
curl c
and so on
```

It works, but sometimes `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host` for some files in the middle of script for example, It will successfully download a but miss the file b with the above error and will download the file c. I would like to catch this error so that my code will execute with the successful download of all the files.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a loop:

```
while true; do
  curl --fail b && break
done
```

The loop won't break until b is downloaded. You can make it a retry function which you can call if a download fails on the first try:

```
retry(){
    while true; do
      curl --fail "$1" && break ||
      echo "Download failed for url: $1
            retrying..."
    done
}
```

Then do this:

```
curl --fail a || retry a
curl --fail b || retry b
curl --fail c || retry c
```

If you just want to silent the  error messages then:

```
curl a 2>/dev/null
curl b 2>/dev/null
...
```

Or if you want to just detect the error then:

```
if ! curl --fail a; then
  echo "Failed"
fi
```

or, a one liner:

```
curl --fail a || echo Failed
```

If you want to exit after a failure and also show your own message:

```
curl --fail a 2>/dev/null || { echo failed; exit 1; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could chain them with `&&`...

```
curl --fail a && curl --fail b && curl --fail c...
```

**Update**: as @nwk pointed out below, we need to add `--fail` to make curl fail on bad http codes.

Comment: Note that this **won't** stop, e.g., on status 404.

Answer (score 2):

Put `set -e` at the beginning of the shell script and use `curl --fail`. E.g.,

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
curl --fail http://example.com/a
curl --fail http://example.com/b
curl --fail http://example.com/c
```

The `set -e` will make the script stop with an error on the first unsuccessful command (one with an exit status ≠ zero).

Comment: I usually don't like added `set -e` to a script as it can be a pain to debug. Chaining might be an option. Or using `set +e` after.

Comment: @andlrc I think having your script fail early *helps* debugging, but that's clearly a matter of preference. I just add `|| true` to commands that I want to allow to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the status of execution of the last command by looking at the `$?` shell variable. 
 Execute command below to check the status of the last command anything other 0 shall indicate an error.

`echo $?`

```
curl a
if [ "$?" -gt 0 ]
then
echo "Error downloading file a. Exiting"
exit
fi 
curl b
if [ "$?" -gt 0 ]
then
echo "Error downloading file b. Exiting"
exit
fi 
...
```

A simple modified form after @andlrc suggestion:

```
if  ! curl a  ; then echo "Got error downloading a";  fi
if  ! curl b  ; then echo "Got error downloading b";  fi
if  ! curl c  ; then echo "Got error downloading c";  fi
```

Comment: or simply `if curl a; then :; else` or `if ! curl a; then`

Comment: I tried doing  `if curl http://madifgss.com  ; then echo "Got error"; fi`. It does not echo "Got error".

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing Use `curl --fail`.

Answer (score 0):

for file2get in a b c d;
do
    do :;
    until curl --fail $file2get;
done

Or add an iterator counter to prevent endless looping